# Escape VueJS data binding syntax in Laravel Blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, vue.js

Laravel templating language Blade and VueJS data binding syntax are very similar.

How can I escape VueJS data binding syntax when in a `*.blade.php` file?

Example:

```
<div>
  <!-- Want it with VueJS -->
  {{ selectedQuestionDesc }}
</div>
<div>
  <!-- Want it with Laravel Blade -->
  {{ $selectedQuestionDesc }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

While asking the question I discovered that you can escape Laravel's Blade by prepending an `@` sign before the double brackets `{{}}` or the `{!! !!}` html rendering brackets.

So here is the answer:

```
<div>
  <!-- HTML rendering with VueJS -->
  @{{ selectedQuestionDesc }} 
  <!-- Data binding with VueJS -->
  @{{ selectedQuestionDesc }}
</div>
<div>
  <!-- HTML with Laravel Blade -->
  {!! $selectedQuestionDesc !!}
  <!-- Variable binding with Laravel Blade -->
  {{ $selectedQuestionDesc }} 
</div>
```

Comment: On the third line of your answer...can you fix that so there are 2 brackets on each side of the binding instead of 3. The edit it too small for me

Comment: @calbear47 can you write an example on a comment and a short description of why the update, please.

Comment: `@{{{ selectedQuestionDesc }}}` should be `@{{ selectedQuestionDesc }}`

Answer (score 1):

In order to output real HTML, you will need to use the v-html directive:

```
<p>Using v-html directive: <span v-html="rawHtml"></span></p>
```