# vue.js: [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: + in laravel blade file

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I have one blade file which prints data from the database.

When someone adds data like below in database then while rendering that page I am facing below issue.

[image]

I have added in below text in the comment. `[{{ auth()->user()->first_name }}]`

[image]

My blade file code to print comment

[image]

the issue is coming because in a comment there are double curly braces,
can someone help me how can I prevent this?

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37934125/3634538) help?

Comment: No,  my code is laravel blade.php file

Comment: and if i use {!!    !!} this tag then it will execute html tags which i dont want @YomS.

Answer (score 0):

To skip Vue from compiling data containing double curly braces (`{{some text}}`) for an element, you could use `v-pre`. This will display raw mustache tags :

```
<span v-pre>[{{ auth()->user()->first_name }}]</span>
```

More : [v-pre](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-pre)