# How to use Laravel Blade syntax inside vuejs directives?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I just started learning vuejs and I'm trying to incorporate it in my laravel project but I'm running into a problem. I have an array of image paths inside my vue object like this:

```
 new Vue({
        el: '#app',

        data: {
            images: [
                "img/image-1.png",
                "img/image-2.png",
                "img/image-3.png"   
            ]
        }
    });
```

I would like to loop through all the images and display them inside my page using the Laravel asset() helper. I tried using it like this:

```
<img v-for="image in images" :src="{{ asset('image') }}">
```

But it doesn't recognize the vue directive:

```
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token ':' in

http://127.0.0.1:8000/image

Raw expression: :src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/image"
```

Comment: Try just `src` without ':'

Comment: That just ignores the vue variable and the path becomes src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/image"

Comment: You can't use asset helper for vue data because laravel renders first and vue renders on client-side so it's impossible. Instead you can try with base url `:src="'{{ url()->to('/') }}/'+image"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to try to iterate the loop like following way:

```
<div v-for="image in images">
    <img :src="image" class="" />
</div>
```

For `assets` helper need below code:

```
<img  src=""  :src="'{{ asset('yourfilepath') }}' +  '/' + image">
```

I hope it will help to you

Comment: This actually works but I've been told to use the asset() helper. I`ll flag it as correct, but do you maybe know when and why you should use the laravel helpers? The documentation doesn't expand on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the VueJS data binding syntax so you can use Blade and Vue at the same time:

Here's the answer, read it for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37934125/9453309

```
<div>
  <!-- HTML rendering with VueJS -->
  @{{ selectedQuestionDesc }} 
  <!-- Data binding with VueJS -->
  @{{ selectedQuestionDesc }}
</div>
<div>
  <!-- HTML with Laravel Blade -->
  {!! $selectedQuestionDesc !!}
  <!-- Variable binding with Laravel Blade -->
  {{ $selectedQuestionDesc }} 
</div>
```

Comment: As I imagine, you want me to do `<img v-for="image in images" src="{{ asset('@{{ image }}') }}">`, but that throws an error `Unclosed '(' does not match '}'`

Comment: @Nutenn No, you need to use double exclamations

`<img v-for="image in images" :src="{{!! asset('image') !!}}">`

Comment: That just throws a similar error: `[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

invalid expression: Unexpected token '}' in

    {http://127.0.0.1:8000/image}

  Raw expression: :src="{http://127.0.0.1:8000/image}"
`

Comment: @Nutenn Oops, I put an extra {}, remove one and try again, it shoud be {!! !!}